# Nwazet.Commerce - Get Cart Count for navigation link

Tags: orchardcms, commerce

Using Nwazet.Commerce module on my Orchard site. Does anyone know how to get the number of items in the cart to show up in a link on the navigation? I'd like for the count to show up on every page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `Views/ShoppingCart.Summary.cshtml` (https://bitbucket.org/bleroy/nwazet.commerce/src/14eeb8cf1495f5b0d8d23ebb70092e644c0d0162/Views/ShoppingCart.Summary.cshtml?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default). It should be as simple as `@items.Count`.